# Get data from car-table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

The model is:

[image]

My action looks like:

```
public function fahrzeugeAction()
{
    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    $userId = $user->getId();

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('FPMAppBundle:Car');

    /* This is the normal Select and it is testet with the mysqlworkbench.
        SELECT c.id, c.description, c.active
        FROM car c
        INNER JOIN customer cu ON cu.id = c.id_customer
        INNER JOIN customer_user cuu ON cuu.id_customer = cu.id
        WHERE c.active = 1 AND cuu.id_user = 1
    */
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('c.id, c.description, c.active')
        ->from('Car', 'c')
        ->innerJoin('Customer', 'cu', 'ON', 'c.idCustomer = cu.id')
        ->innerJoin('CustomerUser', 'cuu', 'ON', 'cu.id = cuu.id_customer')
        ->where('cuu.idUser = ?', $userId)
        ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();

    $cars = $qb->getResult();
    return $this->render( "FPMAllgemeinBundle:Fahrzeuge:overview.html.twig"
        array(
            "cars" => $cars // I know that i have at the moment no variable named $cars
        )
    );
}
```

> Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given

When I use the normal Select-Statement, then i got the right result.

Comment: Using `createQueryBuilder()` you need to build DQL not SQL also update your question by adding your entities definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions would be to move your query from the control into a repository, it seems you already have the a Car repository and are retrieving it.

Repository:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Entity\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CarRepository extends EntityRepository {
    public function myMethodName() {
        try {
            $sql = "SELECT c.id, c.description, c.active
                      FROM car c
                INNER JOIN customer cu ON cu.id = c.id_customer
                INNER JOIN customer_user cuu ON cuu.id_customer = cu.id
                     WHERE c.active = 1
                       AND cuu.id_user = 1";

            $sth = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
            $sth->execute();

            return $sth->fetchAll();
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function fahrzeugeAction() {
    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    $userId = $user->getId();

    $cars = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('FPMAppBundle:Car')
        ->myMethodName();

    return $this->render( "FPMAllgemeinBundle:Fahrzeuge:overview.html.twig"
        array(
            "cars" => $cars
        ));
}
```

My answer returns an array but you can use the query builder within the repository and return an object... both methods work I just prefer my method.